# What does Werner Zytle mean with his final words in S03E01?

Tags: plot-explanation, dialogue, arrow, arrowverse

In the [*Arrow*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2193021/) episode "The Calm" (S03E01), the *Vertigo* legacy of the *Count* is continued by a new villain, *Werner Zytle*, who refined it into some *"scarecrowesque"* fear hallucinogen. When he is captured by *Arrow* at the end of the episode he says:

> Tie me up and lock me down, it doesn't matter. There will always be a Vertigo, always someone to pick up the mantle. You have given it the power, don't you see? Don't you see?

Now I see what he means with the first part, that there will always be people picking up the *Vertigo* business. But **what does he mean with his last sentence that *Arrow* has *"given it the power"*?** Does he mean *Arrow* has actually contributed to the success of *Vertigo* somehow? But in which way? Do his words have any significance or truth to them (maybe in relation to a past episode I can't remember right now) or were this just the ramblings of a madman?

Answer (score 2):

What I think he meant by that was, that because of the Arrow, Vertigo actually became more popular. By stopping it he just made it more exclusive. I remember the papers running about Arrow and Vertigo in the previous encounters. 
What it could also mean is that by creating an antidote, The Arrow actually forced the maker to increase its power, making it stronger than before.